# In c# how does one set the value of the AD property "pwdLastSet"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, change-password

In c# how does one set the value of the AD property "pwdLastSet"

This is not working:

```
DateTime passwordLastSetTarg  = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours( -25 );

var adDate                    = userToActOn.ADEntry.Properties[ "pwdLastSet" ].Value;
long filetime                 = passwordLastSetTarg.ToFileTimeUtc();

userToActOn.ADEntry.Properties[ "pwdLastSet" ][ 0 ] = filetime;
```

This is closely related to my last question, but I hope it's not redundant, if so sorry.

Comment: Your formatting hurts my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set it to a date - only to 0 (expires now) or -1 (reset the time to 'now' )

Comment: That's the behavior I'm seeing. Basically I want my webservice to change the password and ignore the 24 wait rule in ad, so they can immediately reset it on logon. Any way to do this?

Comment: What happens if you just set the password in code? Do you get an exception or does it work?

Comment: The webservice can do it directly, ignoring all AD password based rule,  but the change password stuff uses the Membership provider, so all the other rules will be applied then, like password complexity, it's just specifically the "wait 24 hours" I need to skip and only if it's set via the web service. If i recode the page to use the service, then no rules are ever applied.

Comment: I thought that the DirectoryEntry property for this was not readonly...eg dir_entry_object.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] = 0 (int64 var)...I was not able to set it to zero without this error: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM.

Comment: Also, setting with dir_entry_obj.Properties["pwdLastSet].Value with an int64 var equal to 0 returns: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unspecified error

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misreading the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is a read-only property - as I'd have expected it would be.  It's up to AD to set this as and when a user changes their password.

Comment: I agree this is a read only property, if you use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement the LastPasswordSet property of the UserPrincipal is only get, no set

Comment: You can definitly set it to 0, I didnt' check -1 but I assume it works too, you can't set it to a Int64 FileTime of 25 hours ago, those are the cases I tested.

Comment: FYI not using  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement , but with a DirectoryEntry.